# char.IsWhiteSpace finds space at "wrong" position

Tags: c#, char, whitespace

I am working through the book on a sample code but got a bit confused and struggle to find (probably a simple) answer. I wrote the following code:

```
static void CharFunctionality()
{

    Console.WriteLine("char.IsWhiteSpace('Hello There', 5): {0}", char.IsWhiteSpace("Hello There", 5));
    Console.WriteLine("char.IsWhiteSpace('Hello There', 6): {0}", char.IsWhiteSpace("Hello There", 6));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

when I run it I get the following output:

```
char.IsWhiteSpace('Hello There', 5): True
char.IsWhiteSpace('Hello There', 6): False
```

I would think that this should be the other way around? the 5th character is 'o' and the 6th is 'space'. I hope someone can point me in the right direction on my journey into the world of development  :)

thank you!

Comment: Start counting by 0. Then 5 is a space :-)

Comment: This is unrelated to whitespace characters. String and array indexes start with 0.

Comment: If you're wondering why we start arrays at 0, it has to do with arrays decaying into pointers. This might make more sense if you know some C.

Comment: Try to condense the code you write to it's smallest components when experimenting. Condensing this would for instance have been `Console.WriteLine(char.IsWhiteSpace(" ", 1));` which would yield _System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values..._ - that would (hopefully) have given you clues as to what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you provide is the index of the letter in the string you want to look for. In you first case, it the letter in the 5th index of your strong. In C#, indexes (for arrays or for strings, doesn't matter) always start at index 0.

So in your string "Hello There", 'H' is in the index 0, 'e' is in the index 1, 'l' is in the index 2, etc. That means that the char in the 5th index is a white space.

This works this way in most programming languages. You must always start counting at 0.

Answer (score 5):

String Indexes start from 0 So here in your code :

```
char.IsWhiteSpace('Hello There', 5) //true
char.IsWhiteSpace('Hello There', 6) //false
```

If start from 0 then 5th character will be white space hence the result is true and 6th character is 'T' hence result is false

Answer (score 0):

It's 0 based index.

0-H

1-e

2-l

3-l

4-o

5-[space]

6-T